# How to unit test callback based method (Firebase's verifyPhoneNumber(...))

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, firebase-authentication, callback

I'm trying to unit test a my AuthenticationService class, which acts as an abstraction of Flutter's plugin `firebase_auth`. Specifically, I want to test following method:

```
Future<void> startAuthFlow(String phoneNumber) async {
  await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    verificationCompleted: _onVerificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: _onVerificationFailed,
    codeSent: _onCodeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
  );
}
```

I'm not sure about how to approach the unit testing, as I would like to assure that after SMS is sent, verification is completed, etc, the logic in the private callbacks is executed. However, I don't know how to mock such a function.

I've also thought about the possibility of just unit-testing the callbacks independently, and considering their calling by `_firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber` as subject of an integration test. However, as those callbacks are private, there is no a good way to test them.

Comment: Hello did you find the solution for this because i am also struggling with this.

Comment: @FDjawid I did not